# How to copy files in just generated folders

Tags: python, copy

I want to copy specific files in folders generated through the python script

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import math
import shutil
import glob

for i in range(2,n):
for j in range(2,n):
dirname="be"+str(i)+"-"+str(j)+"-"+str(i*j)
#print(pth+"/"+dirname)
os.mkdir(pth+"/"+dirname)
os.chdir(pth+"/"+dirname)

# Copy files to dirname
f = ['tree', 'leaf', 'forest']
path = '/onyx/..../'

folders = [g for g in glob.glob(path + "**/")]

for g in folders:
print(g)
for i in f:
shutil.copy(os.path.join('/onyx/.../', i), '/onyx/.../g')
```

I expect the items of list f to be copied to the generated folders dirname but the folders are generated without the strings of the list f

Comment: Hello, what is the problem ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: the folders are generated without copying the strings of the list f...